# Laravel 4 Image validation Bug?

Tags: laravel-4

Today, I was using Validation in Laravel 4 and I encountered (maybe) a bug.
This is my validation rules in controller:

```
$rules = array(
        'title'       => 'min:3|max:30|required',
        'price'       => 'numeric|required',
        'avatar'       => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,JPG|max:300',
        'category_id' => 'numeric'
);
```

When I tried to upload an Image greater than 2 MB, Laravel didn't show me image_size error.
But for Images less than 2 MB it worked well.
Then I changed max rule to max:2000, and uploaded an Image greater than 2 MB again. This time Laravel showed me correct message.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: the error could be from your php configuration, try to change the post_max_size and post_max_size in the php.ini file

Comment: Your issue is related this closed Github issue, which is because the way PHP reports the way file sizes are when they exceed your post_max_size. This issue is marked as resolved in Laravel. What version of Laravel are you using? https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2433

Comment: @momo But when I change post_max_size to a larger number like 8 MB, then the problem happens again when I try to upload a 10 MB image. I think it's not the best solution.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange 4.1.28

Comment: if you want an unlimited size of the files set the post_max_size = 0

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related [to this closed Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2433), which is because the way PHP reports the way file sizes are when they exceed your post_max_size.

You need to add 'min' to your rules.

```
$rules = array(
        'title'       => 'min:3|max:30|required',
        'price'       => 'numeric|required',
        'avatar'       => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,JPG|max:300|min:1',
        'category_id' => 'numeric'
);
```

Comment: Try:  'avatar'  => 'between:1,300|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,JPG'

Comment: The :min solution doesnt work for me either. The issue was fixed on Laravel, but reappeared. See here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4467. The Validator needs to be updated, hope someone submits a PR.